# Python: removing duplicate letters from tweets

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, twitter, nlp

Hello dear fellow programmers,
social media comments include much casual language that is characterized by the usage of many characters. An example would be: "Helloooooo!".
For analysis I want to remove these duplicate letters beyond 2 and replace them with exact 2 letters. Our example would be "Helloo!".
I found the corresponding regex. But it also reduces the number of my lines from 500.000 to 450.000. Some lines now contain multiple tweets instead of just one.

example of broken line (the following text should be split into 3 lines, not 1 in the output file:

```
z .. :)"

"USERNAME Am Wochenende gabs das halt fÃ¼r 10 und das DLC fÃ¼r 2,50. Und da das Guthaben hier rumfliegt.. hab ich zugeschlagen :D"

"Wenn das keine #Leseempfehlung ist! Vielen Dank. :) #krimi #sauerland #lesen #lesetipp #rezension URL
```

Code for processing:

```
#repeating letters are set to a limit of 2
#errror: Output file loses 50000 columns. WHy?
import re
with open("C:/Users/M/PycharmProjects/Bachelor_Thesis/test/data_feat2.csv","r", encoding="utf-8") as oldfile1, open('data_feat3.csv', 'w',encoding="utf-8") as newfile1:
    for line in oldfile1:
        line=re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1\1', line) 
        newfile1.write(line)
newfile1.close()
```

Comment: Can you please post a couple of lines of your input file as an example (even better if you could post some of the lines that disappear)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  Most of all, can you post a MCVE, such as a subset of the problem that illustrates losing 2 columns out of 10, with only 20 lines of input?

Answer (score 0):

There could be repeated commas, are they escaped? Search for that in your csv?

Another thing to try is read the file using the csv module and run the regex on each column individually. This would be far slower, but would help you debug.